# How to Install cp-ksql-server Helm Chart that Communicates with Secured Broker

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, ksqldb

I'm trying to connect a KSQLDB Helm chart [cp-ksqldb-server](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/master/charts/cp-ksql-server) with an SSL-secured Kafka broker. The chart I used for the broker is [bitnami/kafka](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/kafka).

I've used this [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/confluentinc/confluent-platform-security-tools/master/kafka-generate-ssl.sh) to create keystore and truststore JKS files. Created secret of these files and passed the secret to the `auth.tls.existingSecrets` parameter in bitnami/kafka helm chart, which is working fine. Followed [this doc](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/infrastructure/kafka/administration/enable-tls/) for the whole process.

Now I'm trying to configure **cp-ksqldb-server** Helm chart to connect to the broker so that the connection is encrypted with SSL. I'm using **SASL_SSL** to connect to the broker. From the [KSQLDB Doc](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/installation/server-config/security/#configuring-kafka-encrypted-communication) I have to pass configuration values like this:

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=<password>
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
sasl.jaas.config=\
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.ScramLoginModule required \
    username="<user>" \
    password="<password>";
```

I have to pass these values in the `configurationOverrides` parameter.

My question is (For [KSQLDB chart](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/master/charts/cp-ksql-server)):

- How do I pass `ssl.truststore.location` value, as my truststore file is in my local machine, and what I'm trying to run is a KSQLDB Helm chart in a Kubernetes cluster?
- Is there any way to pass secret values like bitnami/kafka?
- Is there any way to pass the truststore file by volume binding in this chart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked chart does not support custom volume mounts for external files, which is what you'd need, and [shown how to do](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/infrastructure/kafka/administration/enable-tls/) using `kubectl create secret ... --from-file`

Ref.

- https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/blob/master/charts/cp-ksql-server/templates/deployment.yaml#L72-L76
- https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/blob/master/charts/cp-ksql-server/templates/deployment.yaml#L105

These charts are no longer maintained, so you'd be better off cloning and editing the chart to your needs, anyway.